# HP DL360 G6 raid50 - drive will fall soon

Tags: windows, active-directory, hp

My server have problem with raid battery and in same time one drive have flag: Box 1 bay 3 predicted to fail soon. Also my server 2012 r2 is in mess, error: Online - Cannot get performance counter data, there is lot of error messages in event logs "error on \Device\Harddisk0\DR0".

Server have 6 disks 72gb in raid50. I replace raid battery, but I can not find same hdd to replace. What will hapen if I remove disk that have error and power on server?

Is there any option to repair windows server r2 (it is active directory, print server, fileserver)? I try with win dvd cmd sfc /scannow /offboot... but it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

If you remove a drive the pack where it was in will lose redundancy. Raid50 uses two (or more) raid5 packs in a raid0 manner. If any other drive in the same raid5 pack fails - you will lose all your data.

I assume that you have a P410 controller. It appears to be drive-agnostic, however there are some temperature sensor issues with some drivers. Related info here: http://dascomputerconsultants.com/HPCompaqServerDrives.htm

I think you shall consider replacing the faulty drive with other SAS (check the link however) drive of the same era.